# Is there any way to make Logitech Revolution MX scrolling sensible in OS X?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, mouse, hardware

I'm playing Minecraft on a mac, and I'm using a Logitech Revolution MX. When scrolling in the game, it flicks through my items very quickly, rather than one item-per-click scrolling than I get in Windows. Is there any way to get sensible scrolling through items?

Comment: Does the mouse have smooth scroll on it? If so, replace your mouse.

Comment: @RonanForman The mouse can switch between 'clunky scroll' and smooth scroll. On Windows these behave as expected. On Mac, even clunky scroll behaves like smooth scroll.

Comment: @QAdley Does the MX not have a hardware switch for it? I know my VX did.

Comment: @SaintWacko Yup, but regardless of which mode it's on, the scrolling is smooth.

Comment: I work in an office with a few Macs, and some of the users around here use Logitech mice.  The problem with many of them (that work with both Windows and Mac) is that they behave a little inconsistent-- even between use in OS X and Windows 7, through Parallels.  There might be an answer to your question, however, there is a good chance that this may be a bug that you have to live with.

Comment: @fredley have you tried using the [Logitech Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/software-hidden/3129?section=downloads&bit=32&osid=21) for OS X?

Comment: @Krazer Yes, but I couldn't find any combination of settings that worked

Comment: @fredley Have you fixed the problem yet? Could you share it? Mac OS X's System Preferences give you the ability to change your mouse's behavior. Isn't there a scroll speed setting, or something like that? Even a smooth scrolling checkbox to uncheck?

Comment: @chlkbumper No fix I'm afraid, I've just got used to using the number keys.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware button should properly switch between smooth scrolling and single line scrolling, irrespective of the OS its plugged into.  I'm not sure why its not working for you.

That said, [Logitech Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/mx-revolution) is now supported in OSX, and it works with the Revolution MX.  With this installed, you should be able to tweak the scrolling behavior.

Comment: The hardware button is just a signal to the driver. If the driver on a platform doesn't understand the signal, the switch won't have any effect.

Comment: I was under the impression that the MX Revolution had onboard memory, like the G9 and G9x, but I guess it doesn't.  You can program those two mice in windows, and it remembers their settings when plugged into any computer, any OS.  The hardware button on these mice properly toggles between modes regardless of any software being installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little old, but for anybody searching for a solution, I got a pretty decent one:

Logitech's Control Center is the one doing it! Remove it from your settings / uninstall it. I discovered this after doing a clean install and playing Minecraft for the first time.

To configure which button does what you can use the free and much more advanced software [Better Touch Tool](http://bettertouchtool.net). There are no problems at all when using BTT instead of Logitech's Control Center and there are many more options.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to system preferences > appearance there should be an option to turn off smooth scrolling, I am not sure whether this is for the mouse, or for scrolling windows using the bar at the side however.

Comment: There is no such system preference as 'Appearance', and a search for smooth scrolling has no hits.

Comment: @QAdley My source was [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=774642). Maybe I was reading it wrong.

Comment: That article is from 2008, MacOS has changed quite a bit in 4 years...

Comment: But you haven't tried to turn off smooth scrolling? (The one under System Preferences -> General: 'Use smooth scrolling')

Comment: @Philipp http://imgur.com/RAAaD

Comment: I have it there http://imgur.com/Sr4AI (10.7.4) but anyway, I tried that myself and the scrolling seemed no better. So can't help you right now, sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure what fredley is talking about, as there IS an appearance section that is quite visible from the system preferences panel. Additionally, there also IS a smooth scrolling checkbox as well.

Comment: @fredley Mountain Lion removed the smooth scrolling option. You can disable smooth scrolling in Terminal with the following command:

defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false